# Integrate Google Analytics in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

- I have Google Play Services Revision 24 in the SDK Manager.
- I've added to the dependencies:

  ```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
  ```
- This is my Analytics.xml:

  ```
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-(MY ID)-1</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
  ```
- I have added these lines to the AndroidManifest.xml:

  meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"

Still, Android Studio keep saying 
    "`cannot resolve symbol analytics\easyTracker`".

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What version of analytics are you using?  That xml looks like it's for v2, the latest is v4.

Comment: Thanks, I had a mix from all kinds of resourses. Now it's working :)

Comment: I paste a link to a tutorial that helped me with it, for other users: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMZMZuIk5LM